# How can I view FPS in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am trying to play with the optimal settings regarding game performance.
But yet again, I still enjoy playing with some great graphical settings.

To balance this out, I would love to know;

- **Are there any way that I can see my FPS in-game?**
- **Or track the FPS after a game?**

*(EDIT: I often use the unit preloader aswell - I can recommend this)*

Comment: You can use Fraps for displaying fps

Comment: @spyder wouldent Fraps have a negative influence on the FPS of the game? Then it wouldent be acurate.

Comment: You can use Fraps for displaying the fps without recording

Comment: @AtlasEU Fraps has a negligible impact on performance in games, unless you're recording videos with it. If you're only using it to monitor your game's FPS, then the performance impact should be almost the same as a built-in FPS counter's.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Starcraft 2, if playing on Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> should show you your fps.

On a Mac, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

It should appear in the upper left hand corner.

Comment: It worked on MacOS with Control + Option + F